# Multiplying using Summation rule

Tags: summation

Is the sum
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{2}\sum_{j=1}^{2}x_i  $$

equals to

$$\sum_{i=1}^{2}x_i ?$$

Comment: What "sum of j=1 to j=2 of xI" means?

Comment: I meant x subscript I

Comment: Isn't it just $2x_i$?

Comment: you can use mathjax to format your math expressions.read this also when you post a question next time http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Is this what you want to ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
   \left(\sum_{i=1}^2 x_i \right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^2 x_j \right) 
&= (x_1 + x_2)(x_1 + x_2) \\
&= x_1^2 + 2x_1 x_2 + x_2^2,
\end{align*}
unless I'm missing something ...

**EDIT:**

After reading your edited question, I see now what you are asking:
$$
   \sum_{i=1}^2 \sum_{j=1}^2 x_i 
= \sum_{i=1}^2 x_i \sum_{j=1}^2 1 
= 2\sum_{i=1}^2 x_i 
= 2(x_1 + x_2).
$$
You can take $x_i$ out of the sum on $j$ because it doesn't depend on $j$.